# How to calculate and creates new columns based on difference between rows in pyspark Data Drame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My DF looks like below:

```
objid|gpstime            | gpsspeed|
+------+-------------------+-----
|X   |2018-04-03 11:00:40|       10|
|X   |2018-04-03 11:00:47|       15|
|X   |2018-04-03 11:00:50|       10|
|Y   |2018-04-03 11:00:52|       30|
|Y   |2018-04-03 11:00:59|       50|
```

The result should be like this below:

```
objid|gpstime|          gpsspeed|timeDiff |speedDiff|
+------+-------------------+--------+---------+---------+
|X|2018-04-03 11:00:40|       10|        -|         |
|X|2018-04-03 11:00:47|       15|        7|        5|
|X|2018-04-03 11:00:50|       10|        3|       -5|
|Y|2018-04-03 11:00:52|       30|        2|       20|
|Y|2018-04-03 11:00:59|       50|        7|       20|
```

So I need to create 2 new columns based on difference from existig ones but I have an issues. My code from one columns looks like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("time_intertweet", datediff(df.gpstime, lag(df.gpstime, 1)
.over(Window.partitionBy("gpstime")
.orderBy("gpstime"))))
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not partition by anything because you want to get the previous row without any partitioning. Also, if you want to get the time difference in seconds, you probably want to use `unix_timestamp` instead of `datediff` (which returns difference in number of days).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, lag
from pyspark.sql import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "timeDiff", 
    unix_timestamp(df.gpstime) - unix_timestamp(lag(df.gpstime, 1).over(Window.orderBy("gpstime")))
).withColumn(
    "speedDiff",
    df.gpsspeed - lag(df.gpsspeed, 1).over(Window.orderBy("gpstime"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for help but now I get "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'over'". I didn't get it before

Comment: you probably did something like `df.over(...)`. maybe a typo in your code somewhere?

Comment: Although the above solution is correct , Window operation without partition column will end up moving all the data to a single partition or a single node and must be avoided for big data.     WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.